# Using AVAssetWriter with raw NAL Units

Tags: iphone, ios, h.264, avassetwriter, cmsamplebufferref

I noticed in the iOS documentation for `AVAssetWriterInput` you can pass `nil` for the `outputSettings` dictionary to specify that the input data should not be re-encoded.

> The settings used for encoding the media appended to the output. Pass nil to specify that appended samples should not be re-encoded.

I want to take advantage of this feature to pass in a stream of raw H.264 NALs, but I am having trouble adapting my raw byte streams into a `CMSampleBuffer` that I can pass into AVAssetWriterInput's `appendSampleBuffer` method. My stream of NALs contains only SPS/PPS/IDR/P NALs (1, 5, 7, 8). I haven't been able to find documentation or a conclusive answer on how to use pre-encoded H264 data with AVAssetWriter. The resulting video file is not able to be played.

How can I properly package the NAL units into `CMSampleBuffers`? Do I need to use a start code prefix? A length prefix? Do I need to ensure I only put one NAL per `CMSampleBuffer`? My end goal is to create an MP4 or MOV container with H264/AAC.

Here's the code I've been playing with:

```
-(void)addH264NAL:(NSData *)nal
{
    dispatch_async(recordingQueue, ^{
        //Adapting the raw NAL into a CMSampleBuffer
        CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = NULL;
        CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer = NULL;
        CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = NULL;
        CMItemCount numberOfSampleTimeEntries = 1;
        CMItemCount numberOfSamples = 1;


        CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCMVideoCodecType_H264, 480, 360, nil, &formatDescription);
        OSStatus result = CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, [nal length], kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, 0, [nal length], kCMBlockBufferAssureMemoryNowFlag, &blockBuffer);
        if(result != noErr)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error creating CMBlockBuffer");
            return;
        }
        result = CMBlockBufferReplaceDataBytes([nal bytes], blockBuffer, 0, [nal length]);
        if(result != noErr)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error filling CMBlockBuffer");
            return;
        }
        const size_t sampleSizes = [nal length];
        CMSampleTimingInfo timing = { 0 };
        result = CMSampleBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, blockBuffer, YES, NULL, NULL, formatDescription, numberOfSamples, numberOfSampleTimeEntries, &timing, 1, &sampleSizes, &sampleBuffer);

        if(result != noErr)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error creating CMSampleBuffer");
        }
        [self writeSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer ofType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    });
}
```

Note that I'm calling `CMSampleBufferSetOutputPresentationTimeStamp` on the sample buffer inside of the `writeSampleBuffer` method with what I think is a valid time before I'm actually trying to append it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: At least part of my problem was how I was dealing with CMSampleTimingInfo. I mentioned I was using `setOutputPresentationTimeStamp` to fill in a real timestamp. I now realize that I need to also fill in the other fields of CMSampleTimingInfo. I'm setting `decodeTimeStamp` to `kCMTimeInvalid` and `duration` to `CMTimeMake(1, 30)`. I now get a seekable video container with a proper total time, but there's no video (testing in VLC).

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get video playback working in VLC but not QuickTime. I used code similar to what I posted above to get H.264 NALs into CMSampleBuffers.

I had two main issues:

1. I was not setting CMSampleTimingInfo correctly (as my comment above states).
2. I was not packing the raw NAL data correctly (not sure where this is documented, if anywhere).

To solve #1, I set `timing.duration = CMTimeMake(1, fps);` where fps is the expected frame rate. I then set `timing.decodeTimeStamp = kCMTimeInvalid;` to mean that the samples will be given in decoding order. Lastly, I set `timing.presentationTimeStamp` by calculating the absolute time, which I also used with `startSessionAtSourceTime`.

To solve #2, through trial and error I found that giving my NAL units in the following form worked:

```
[7 8 5] [1] [1] [1]..... [7 8 5] [1] [1] [1]..... (repeating)
```

Where each NAL unit is prefixed by a 32-bit start code equaling `0x00000001`.

Presumably for the same reason it's not playing in QuickTime, I'm still having trouble moving the resulting .mov file to the photo album (the `ALAssetLibrary` method `videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum` is failing stating that the "Movie could not be played." Hopefully someone with an idea about what's going on can comment. Thanks!

Comment: Given that this only works in VLC, there's a chance that I need to change the way I'm packing the NALs into the buffers in order for QuickTime to work. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I took a hexdump of the resulting mov file and it looks like there exists one mdat atom towards the top of the file as well as a couple avc1 atoms towards the bottom, but no avcC atom. Inside the mdat atom seemed to be the stream of NALs I describe in this answer (separated by the 0x00000001 prefix). I'm assuming QuickTime refuses to play the file because the data under the mdat is in Annex-B format and because there exists no avcC atom. I need to figure out how to feed the data to AVAssetWriterInput properly.

Comment: I managed to get everything working. I am prepending the NAL length to each NAL (instead of 0x00000001), and I also managed to properly pass the avcC data into the mov container. See my question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673379/avassetwriterinput-h-264-passthrough-to-quicktime-mov-passing-in-sps-pps-to/