# What does packing nal packets mean?

Tags: objective-c, video-capture, h.264, pack

I have been trying to use the information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629117/using-avassetwriter-with-raw-nal-units) to solve a similar problem.

However, from the answer; I am not sure what is meant by the following:

> I was not packing the raw NAL data correctly (not sure where this is
>   documented, if anywhere).

or even the solution to this packing issue.

> To solve #2, through trial and error I found that giving my NAL units
>   in the following form worked:
>
> ```
> [7 8 5] [1] [1] [1]..... [7 8 5] [1] [1] [1]..... (repeating)
> ```
>
> Where each NAL unit is prefixed by a 32-bit start code equaling
>   0x00000001.

I have seen similar expression concerning nal packets.  The original post from the link above has a statement that says:

> My stream of NALs contains only SPS/PPS/IDR/P NALs (1, 5, 7, 8)

Again, what does this mean?  How would I pack raw NAL data correctly in objective-c?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called `H.264 Annex B byte stream format` (defined in ISO/IEC 14496-12).
http://wiki.multimedia.cx/?title=H.264

I think, below page has very good explanation:
http://gentlelogic.blogspot.kr/2011/11/exploring-h264-part-2-h264-bitstream.html

There are many open source implementations about this (not easily reusable though).

---

NAL AU is the unit of data to encapsulate an encoded frame data. It is consist of header (start code), type, length, and body part.

SPS/PPS/IDR/P are frame types.

SPS : config information about overall stream (encoding method, parameter, etc)
PPS : config information about pictures (width, height, etc)
IDR : special frame/packet to setup decoder
P : usual encoded frame data

Order of frame in ordinary movie files: SPS (once) PPS (once) IDR (periodically) P (actual picture) P P P P P IDR P P P P P P P ...

---

For annex B byte stream processing, Intel IPP code samples are very good reference (umc_h264_nal_spl.cpp).
Its currently free to download (latest version is free to evaluate 30 days).
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/code-samples-for-intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-library-71

Annex B byte stream format describes how to store H.264 encoded frame data in a media container (such as mp4, MPEG 2 TS). Handling the container format binary data also requires many hard works. Each container uses different mechanism to specify codec configuration. As mentioned related SO post ([AVAssetWriterInput H.264 Passthrough to QuickTime (.mov) - Passing in SPS/PPS to create avcC atom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673379/avassetwriterinput-h-264-passthrough-to-quicktime-mov-passing-in-sps-pps-to/)), mp4/mov uses `avcc` box format which is defined in other ISO/IEC document.

Comment: thanks 9dan.  I have looked at xmbc, vlc, ffmpeg, ect ...; alot of etcs. lol.  But trying to get it to work with OSX frameworks have been my issue.  With much searching, I think I am not 'packing' my data correctly, before I get to format descriptors, sample buffers, decompressing and decoding.  You have sent me some great resources.  This will be hundreds of pages of reading, but I guess I should have started with these docs in the first place.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user2517182 updated my post with some additional notes.